# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^n{x}}{(1+r^2-2r\cos{x})^{(n+2)/2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{1-r^2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^n{x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that
>
> $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{\sin^n{x}}{(1+r^2-2r\cos{x})^{(n+2)/2}}\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{1-r^2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^n{x}\,\mathrm dx,$$
> where $n\ge 1, n\in \Bbb N,|r|<1.$

I think use
$$\dfrac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos{x}+r^2}=1+2\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}r^m\cos{(mx)},$$
where $|r|<1.$

But it is very ugly.

Comment: Could you please stop numerating your problems? I think that this is really silly.  Why you just don't solve both sides ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I think you can edit the titles.

Comment: @RonGordon, that would be such a minor change, thats it not worth an edit in my opinion, and I don't want to clean up behind him (as (15) indicates there are 14 more to edit)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Though I agree that math110 may improve how he post questions, you should be more polite to give your advice.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants, for whatever reason, to keep track of the problems he's posted here. Nothing wrong with that imo, though perhaps the numbering should be written in a less conspicuous place, if possible.

Comment: If a user wishes to keep track of the questions he has posted, can he not just use the 'question' section of his homepage?

Comment: Regarding the numbering, only two other questions by the OP ask to compute an integral (one unnumbered and one numbered (10)). Thus the present numbering (15) does not refer to questions asked on MSE, and, as such, it is only distracting for the users of the site. Not unrelated, trying to give more informative titles might be a first step towards a more constructive stance by the OP. In the present case, the [Poisson kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) is involved, and a decent title would refer to this. .../...

Comment: .../... Finally, the OP was already informed, à propos another question, that one does not "solve" an integral (but one can compute them). All in all, I think @DominicMichaelis is doing a service to all by drawing attention (maybe not in an optimal way) to these.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I got this to check out in Mathematica, although it did take a little manipulation to get signs right in the intermediate steps.

Comment: Thanks Ron...but what does that mean? Am I right or wrong, according to Mathematica?

Comment: So, @math110, is your formula right or wrong? I claim it is wrong at least for $\,n=1\,$ ...

Comment: Title edited: while it may be convenient for OP, it does not help people who use MSE to see such numbers (and what if everybody does this with it's own numbering scheme?)

Comment: @DonAntonio Your computation is wrong, starting from and including the step $\left(1+r^2+2r-(1+r^2-2r)\right)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @math110 I wonder why you do not see fit to react to DonAntonio's query nor to any of the suggestions made to you about the formatting of your questions and the need to include at least some personal thoughts about them.

Comment: @Did , somehow the last the last line in my comment came out messed up. The colored part should be $$-\frac{2}{r^{3/2}}$$but, of course, this is not that important: my point was remarking to the OP that apparently his integrals' euqality was not right, at least for $\,n=1\,$, unless I made some mistake. He though never answered...

Comment: @DonAntonio You DID make a mistake and everything after and including the step I indicated is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, oh...thanks a lot, @did: you are so wonderful...but would you mind telling me **WHERE** is the mistake or your work ends at remarking that??

Comment: @DonAntonio What was that?? Did you eat something strange for dinner? Although your last comment is a strong incentive not to, let me indicate that $\left(1+r^2+2r-(1+r^2-2r)\right)^{-1/2}$ is not $\left(1+r^2+2r\right)^{-1/2}-\left(1+r^2-2r\right)^{-1/2}$ (but after that, you are on your own, whichever inappropriate remark you see fit to make).

Comment: I had a very nice dinner, thanks and, apparently, you didn't. Try to be a little more propositive next time and make yourself clear, lest you'll continue to get rash reactions from other (or me, say) when you write disgusting, unclear remarks.

Comment: @DonAntonio You definitely had something strange for dinner. Tell me, how is to signal that some computations in some (now erased) comments are wrong, a "disgusting, unclear remark" in your book? As far as I can see, I got you out of the mathematical mess you put yourself into--and this would not be "propositive"? There are two "disgusting" comments on this page, yours from Mar 31 at 14:36 and yours from Mar 31 at 18:27 (but you delete a lot...).

Comment: I deleted the comment because it was wrong.. It has no bearing whatsoever with you or with what I wrote to you as a reaction to your disgusting remark in capitals. If you want, and you should, to call somebody's attention to some mistake say it clearly and without irrelevants remarks. I usually am into several mathematical realms at some given time and have no time to guess what mistake some brat has to suggest vaguely. So abide by your first impression and do *not* remark anything about my posts here *unless* you do so c-l-e-a-r-l-y...perhaps you should smoke?

Answer (score 1):

The integral in the LHS is a partial case of formula 3.665.2 from Gradshteyn & Ryzhik. The integral in the RHS also is well-known (ibid 3.621.1 ). I don't find any motivation to reinvent the wheel.